# How to use php and javascript to add/sub hours to a mysql datetime string

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the datetime string returned from a mysql query.  I want to add/sub hours (timezone support) dynamically.  These mysql datetime strings are saved in hidden html page elements for javascript manipulation.

The first rendering of the page processes the mysql datetime string based on a user selected 'default' timezone.  Javascript will change these values later if the user desires.

1. How do you add hours to a mysql datetime string using php?
2. How do you add hours to a mysql datetime string using javascript?

I've seen some pretty exotic manipulations to obtain these zone adjusted values, but there must be an easy way of just adding/sub a couple hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP you can use a DateTime Object and then use the add method:

```
$datestring = "2016-05-01 12:30:00"; // This would come from the SQL database
$date = new DateTime($datestring);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
```

The documentation for `DateTime::add()` can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

It takes a DateInterval as an argument, the documentation for the DateInterval format is here:
http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

For Javascript I have found the `Moment` library very useful: http://momentjs.com/

Just like the PHP object you can create a new `Moment` instance and call the add method:

```
var datestring = "2016-05-01 12:30:00"; //Again this would come from your backend database
var day = moment(datestring);
day = day.add(2, "hours");
```

## UPDATE

If you don't want to use `Moment` you could use the `Date` object in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
var date = new Date(datestring);
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 2); // Adds 2 hours 
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 20); // Adds 20 mins
```

Comment: Perfect.  It barked awhile until I changed your 'h' to 'H'  Terrific answer.  Thanks.  Now on to the javascript.

Comment: I also added a simpler approach for `Javascript`

Comment: Obligatory plug for [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/), which turns `$date->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));` into stuff like `$date->addHours(2)`

Comment: Nice, haven't seen that before but looks pretty useful

Comment: I started with the Date object but surrendered to the moment after beginning a date format.  100K isn't that big a file but I thought there would be a compressed version.  I couldn't find one.  Is there?

Answer (score 1):

```
       new Date (new Date().toDateString('yourdate') + ' ' + '00:30');
```

Codepen URL for reference-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WxwGrE

Where i am adding 30mins to the date value which i have defined which you ca replace with the data from the database and you add/sub hours,mins and even secs